# An issue with melt function in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset `data` that is:

```
Time1    Time2    Time3    Time4    Time5    Time6    Time7    Time8
0.25     0.68     0.22     0.125    0.97     0.81     0.025    0.641
```

When I use the `melt()` function using `reshape2` package to transfer the data into long-format data as `melt(data)`, I get the following issue:

```
No id variables; using all as measure variables
```

What can I do avoid this issue?

Comment: R doesn't have a melt function. Maybe mention your required packages.

Comment: Have you looked at exemples? Have you read `?melt`? What package are you talking about?

Comment: Maybe just transpose `t()`?

Comment: That's just a message, not a warning or error. If you specify `id.vars = NULL`, it will go away.

Answer (score -1):

`reshape2` has been replaced with [tidyr](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org) now, so you might want to check out the functions in that package. Reshaping to long is now covered by [`gather`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html)

```r
library(readr)
library(tidyr)

df <- readr::read_table("Time1    Time2    Time3    Time4    Time5    Time6    Time7    Time8
0.25     0.68     0.22     0.125    0.97     0.81     0.025    0.641")

gather(df, "key", "value")

#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>     key value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Time1 0.250
#> 2 Time2 0.680
#> 3 Time3 0.220
#> 4 Time4 0.125
#> 5 Time5 0.970
#> 6 Time6 0.810
#> 7 Time7 0.025
#> 8 Time8 0.641
```